# Understanding Funtions

Tags: list, ocaml

What is this function doing?

```ml
let minium (l: int list) :int option =

  begin match l with
  | [] -> None
  | x::rest -> Some (fold min x rest)

end
```

I think that it takes in an int list, goes through all elements, and returns the minimum. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, if we assume that `fold` has the same meaning as `List.fold_left` the function returns `Some x`, where x is  the minimum value of the given list. Since an empty list has no minimum value, it returns `None` for that case. My advice is to make sure you understand how `fold` works in detail.

Answer (score 0):

The begin and end statements are superfluous. Here's a cleaned up version of the code.

```
let minimum (l: int list) : int option =
  match l with
  | [] -> None
  | x::rest -> Some (List.fold_left min x rest)
```

I'll walk through what the code will do to a list of integers.

If the integer list is the empty list, `[]` it will return None. If there's no list there's no minimum.

Let's evaluate an example list, `lst = [1;2;3;4;5]`.

`minimum lst` ≡ `Some (List.fold_left min 1 [2;3;4;5]`

You can check the implementation of List.fold_left here:

```
let rec fold_left (f : 'a -> 'b ->'a) (acc : 'a) (l : 'b list): 'a =
  match l with
    [] -> acc
  | x :: rest -> fold_left f (f acc x) rest
```

≡ `Some (List.fold_left min (min 1 2) [3;4;5])`

≡ `Some (List.fold_left min 1 [3;4;5])`

≡ `Some (List.fold_left min (min 1 3) [4;5])`

≡ `Some (List.fold_left min 1 [4;5])`

≡ `Some (List.fold_left (min 1 4) [5])`

≡ `Some (List.fold_left min 1 [5])`

≡ `Some (List.fold_left (min 1 5) [])`

≡ `Some (List.fold_left min 1 [])`

≡ `Some 1`

The function `List.fold_left` will apply the min to every element of the list, save the result each time to an accumulator (which in this case starts as the first element of the list) and when we eventually get to the end of the list returns the accumulator.